# how to make an asynchronous call to model and controller and get its values in views?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, backbone.js

I'm trying to make a instant search like application in Ruby On Rails and Backbone.js .

I have stored all the words in a Model named `Dictionary`. It contains list of all the words. 
Now, I want to make a search bar, where if I type "c" , I want list all the words starting with "c" similarly, if I type "ca" , It should list all the words starting with "ca".

Is there a Open Source application , from where I can learn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this code. There might be typos, but I think it would work. Please comment so I can edit if it doesn't work

view

```
<%= text_field_tag 'search', :nil, :class => "search_box" %>
 <ul class="results">
    <span class="spinning" style="display:none;"></span>
 </ul>
```

jquery

```
$(".search_box").keyup(function(){
    $.get ("/search/" + this.value)
    $(".spinning").show()
)}
```

routes.rb

```
get "/search/:search" => "dictionaries#search", :as => :search
```

dictionaries_controller.rb

```
def search
 @dictionarys = Dictionary.where("word LIKE ?", params[:search])
end
```

views/dictionarys/search.js.erb

```
$(".results").empty().append("<%= j( render @dictionaries) %>"
$(".spinning").hide()
```

views/dictionarys/_dictionary.html.erb partial

```
<li><%=dictionary.word%></li>
```

Comment: Not exactly error, if I use simple $(".results").append("aasd") it works. i.e. it appends aasd on each keydown. However, using $(".results").append(j render @dictionaries) nothing is getting appended.

Comment: Finally, it worked, I used : $(".results").append("<%= escape_javascript(  render @dictionaries) %>")

Comment: There is one problem with this solution. my render function is getting called the number of words in the Dictionary that matches with the current text. for example, if 2 words matches "ab" i.e. "abcd" and "abxy" then I am getting this output : "abcd"\n"abxy"\n"abcd"\n"abxy". What could be possible reason for this?

Comment: I added $(".results").empty() in the callback (views/dictionarys/search.js.erb). This will empty the results div between keyups

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `auto_complete`, and connect AJAX call with it for taking the values from the database. See the [jQuery Autocomplete documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: This is autocomplete. what I am asking is completely different. My question is, how can I list words from Dictionary . my focus is more on Ajax part of the question .

Comment: Ok, I got that. Making ajax call only, you have to write the query like: `@words = Dictionary.all(:conditions=>["word LIKE ?", "ca%"])`

Comment: But this query will be in controllers, right?
I want to display the result of this query in my views in real time.

Comment: @d34th4ck3r, Yes. The results will be in controllers. They have to be sent back to client in JSON format and read there in onsuccess() method of ajax call.

Comment: how exactly do I send it back to client (without refreshing the page) ?

Comment: You can use jQuery ajax. And give the format in the controller as :js.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

Onclick() in GUI, do an ajax call to ruby server, which the entered data as key.

Use class variable in the ruby side to load your dictionary data only once so that you need not do db fetch everytime.

Now do regex match on ruby side, and send the data to GUI, onsuccess() of this ajax call load the GUI widget accordingly.

Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Your solution is clear. But can you help me with "do an ajax call to ruby server" by giving an example ? I am unable to get this part.

Comment: Have you tried making an Ajax call to the application from GUI? I did not get your problem. What is said was simply this.
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first